# How are connections in TCP recorded for sending messages one after another?

Tags: tcp

In transport layer, TCP is connection oriented and UDP are connectionless.

What is "connection" as in TCP then?

In network layer, is it correct that there should be no distinction between TCP and UDP, and no concept "connection"?
Is a "connection" corresponding to a fixed route in the network layer?

Multiple messages can be sent one after another using the same connection.
How is a connection recorded/memorized? Is it memorized only by the endpoints of communication, or also by the intermediaries (routers, gateway, proxy, ...)?

Comment: _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793#section-1.5)_ defines TCP. "_Connections: The reliability and flow control mechanisms described above require that TCPs initialize and maintain certain status information for each data stream. The combination of this information, including sockets, sequence numbers, and window sizes, is called a connection. Each connection is uniquely specified by a pair of sockets identifying its two sides._"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `TCP` and `UDP` are [communication protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol), clarifying rules on how entities can communicate with each other. They are used over the `IP` protocol which again defines the information a packet should have for its correct redirection to its destination

[Check the structure of an IPv4 packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure). Packet header information will be used by the midpoints for your packet to reach its destination. So on network layer there isn't the concept of `UDP` or `TCP` and u cant really make a distinction out of them.

When you are using `UDP` you will be encapsulating at the data section of the IP packet a `UPD` packet with [this structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) and extra information, same goes for `TCP` only this time the [packet header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) carries a lot more information.

For example `TCP` header has a field with sequence number , this helps to enumerate packets that arrive out of order due to random delays each packet has been through or help for the retransmission of a lost packet

The extra information a `TCP` header has ( 10 mandatory fields while UDP has 4) is utilized to create the concept of  "connection" . In `TCP`  an established connection should provide reliable, ordered, and error-checked delivery of a stream of octets (bytes)

Comment: Thanks.  Is an actual connection implemented only in the network layer? Is TCP only providing virtual connection, because its underlying IP protocol is connectionless?

Comment: The network layer has no concept of connections. There is no relationship between packets (except for fragments).

Answer (score 5):

> In network layer, is it correct that there should be no distinction
>   between TCP and UDP, and no concept "connection"?

Yes. At the network layer, there is no relationship between packets. Each one is sent individually.

> How is a connection recorded/memorized? Is it memorized only by the
>   endpoints of communication, or also by the intermediaries (routers,
>   gateway, proxy, ...)?

Only the endpoints. Routers, etc, operate at the network layer and process individual packets. They do not have any concept of connection.

Comment: Thanks.  Underlying a "connection" in TCP, is there a fixed route (endpoints, routers, etc) in the network layer?

Comment: @Tim No. Each packet finds its own way between source and destination. They can all take the same path or different ones. The network layer doesn't care about the "connection" and the transport layer doesn't care about routing.

Comment: @Zac67 What is a TCP connecton then, if all the messages in a TCP connection can take different network layer route? Looks like no difference from UDP

Comment: A TCP connection is a logical connection between two endpoints. It's established by the SYN-SYN/ACK-ACK handshake. A UDP datagram is just sent over without any preparation. You could also call a TCP socket a virtual connection because the underlying network layer doesn't know about it.

Comment: TCP provides reliable connection and flow control. Both are missing in UDP

Comment: @Zac67 "You could also call a TCP socket a virtual connection because the underlying network layer doesn't know about it.". Is an actual connection implemented only in the network layer? Is TCP only providing virtual connection, because its underlying IP protocol is connectionless?

Comment: The network layer has no concept of connection. There are no relationships between packets ( except for fragments).

Comment: @Tim There's no "actual connection" in a packet-switched network (above the physical layer) other than those transport-layer connections that I'd call virtual or logical.